# 400 LED string of Xmas lights

Tags: led

I have a set of xmas LED lights (400)
After a short use the lights developed a fault, about the first100 lights are on then 100 off then 100 on then the last100 off there are also a few here and there that are off.
On checking the wires 2 wires come from the controller , one goes to the first LED which then divides into 2 then each LED has 2 in 2 out all up the string.
The other wire flows the full length and joins the end.
What could be wrong and how do I fix

Comment: You did not provide enough info. Bring the maximum possible. Draw schematics, post the photos of string, leds, power supply, controller, etc

Comment: IF we could work out the circuit arrangement good advice should be able to be give. Knowing voltage across lit LEDs would help - noting that they are connected to mains probably (you did not say what Vin is or where it comes from. We can often work miracles with partial data but the impossible is sometimes too hard.

Comment: Your wiring description is ambiguous enough as to not be clear. Can you sketch the arrangement. A photo or few also may help. Help us help you. We still have 11+ months to Christmas so we shouild have time to work it out :-).